# ReactJS - Serving the Same Build from Different Paths

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

I try to run the same react app on different URLs but for now without success.

**Description of the problem:**

I have a react app that works perfectly fine when running both on localhost and on production url when served as a root (e.g `www.myApp.com`)

however what I'm trying to achieve is to have the same app run both on `www.myApp.com` and on `www.anotherSite.com/myApp`

**What I've tried:**

So I took a look at the Deployment section that can be found here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

and I tried setting the `homepage` to `"."` but this ends in a situation where:

1. `www.myApp.com` works as expected which is good
2. `www.anotherSite.com/myApp` does not work at all -> white page with error showing
   [image]

I think it's the same problem that this guy has:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9183

3. `www.anotherSite.com/myApp/` (notice the `/` at the end) works but the paths are not working (I get redirected to my 404 Page).

I played arround with different combinations of the `homepage`, setting the `basename` for the `Router` and setting the `<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/"/>` in `index.html`
but nothing really works for both cases.

I was able to run the app on `www.anotherSite.com/myApp` by setting `homepage: "/myApp/"` but then `www.myApp.com` does not work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?